# JQuery AJAX url call - sometimes don't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, url

I use JEasyUI framework in a page, and I have a form that calls an URL on submit which does some DB work.
Here is the function calling URL (which is defined in another function earlier in the code):

```js
function saveClientItem() {
  console.log("Save Client Item, url:" + url);
  $('#formClientItem').form('submit', {
    url: url,
    onSubmit: function() {
      return $(this).form('validate');
      return false;
    },
    success: function(result) {
      console.log("Success saving client item with url:" + url);
      $('#windowClientItem').dialog('close');
      $('#tableClientsList').datagrid('reload');
    }
  });
};
```

On some computers the page works fine, but on other computers it sporadically calls the URL, but always returns "success". Here is an excerpt from the Chrome console and network log on the computer where it works as it should:
[image: Log from computer where it works fine]

I marked the "clients.php" which is called to do the DB work.

Here is an excerpt from the Chrome console and network log on the computer where it doesn't work as expected:

[image: Log from the computer where it works sporadically]

I have tried clearing the cache on the second computer, refreshing with Ctrl+F5, after that the page works a few times, and then back to not calling the URL. So far I tried on 4 computers with various results, 50-50 works-fails.
I need a hint on what to check with the computers where it doesn't work, or maybe another fail-proof way of submitting the form to a PHP page.

I added "error" event to function,

```js
error: function(result) {
  console.log("error saving client item with url:" + url);
}
```

...and what puzzles me is that "success" is always called. I realise that something is preventing URL to be called (guessing some network issue), but shouldn't "error" event be raised?

Comment: Can you share more details? What have you tried to check **why** this happens? Is sending the request a problem, receiving the request by the backend server, sending back the response, handling the response?

Answer (score 0):

After trying:

- Changing jEasyUI version from 1.9.7 to 1.4.2
- Changing jQuery versin from 1.13.1 to 3.5.1

...with the same problem occurring every time (even after emptying cache and all browser data), I tried putting the function in a loop and called it up to 100 times with some random values to be posted, and the "clients.php" file was called randomly: sometimes after 1 try, sometimes after 17 tries, sometimes it was never called.
I ended up modifying my function to look like this:

```js
function saveClientItem() {
  $('#formClientItem').form('submit', {
    url: url,
    onSubmit: function() {
      $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: url,
          data: $(this).serialize()
        })
        .done(function(data) {
          console.log("Posting success:" + data);
          $('#windowClientItem').dialog('close');
          $('#tableClientsList').datagrid('reload');
        })
        .fail(function() {
          console.log("Posting failed.");
        });
      // prevent refreshing the page
      return false;
    }
  });
};
```

Put in a loop of 100 consequent submits it submits every time (tested about 10 times so far), whereas the old function is still quirky.
I hope this helps someone.